# How Spring Boot Autowired and Post Construct work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have three classes as following -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    Test2 test2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        test2.SayHello();
    }

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("print me is called in Bean B");
    }
}

@Component
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    Test test;

    @PostConstruct
    public void SayHello(){
        System.out.println("Test2");
        test.sayHi();
    }
}
```

Now this one throws exception -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test2': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, if I change the class Test2 as follows -

```
    @Component
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    Test test;

    @PostConstruct
    public void SayHello(){
        System.out.println("Test2");
        test.printMe();
    }
}
```

This one works. If it had to fail, why it did not fail in both the cases?
Or if it had to succeed, why it did not succeed in both the cases?

How Spring initialization with autowired and post constructor work?

Answer (score 1):

Spring instantiates beans and injects dependencies for them according to their relation.
Spring guarantees that a declared bean will have all its dependencies injected/set before that it invokes its method annotated `@PostConstruct`.

Here the relations between the beans :

> Test --uses--> Test2
>
> Test2 --uses--> Test

Here how it works :

1) Spring instantiates a bean and then the other without injecting their dependencies.  So far, the order doesn't matter.
2) Spring injects dependencies for a first bean. Since here dependencies are bi-directional, Spring decides arbitrarily which bean to handle firsrt. In your case, according to your error, Spring handles first `Test2`.
3) Spring invokes the `@PostConstruct` method of the `Test2` bean after setting its dependencies.
The method you defined invokes the method of the `Test` bean that uses a dependency field (`Test2 test2`).
But since dependencies of that bean were not set yet,
that field is null and access it triggers NPE.

In your working case, you invoke from `Test2` a `Test` method that doesn't refer to its dependency fields.

Note that cyclic dependencies are generally not recommended. Here is an illustration of problems that it may produce.
When you cannot remove them, you should at least avoid invoking the other bean in the `@PostConstruct` method because it defeats the job done by the container to break the cycle during their initialization.